# svnant - parent dir in server is not a working copy

Tags: svn, ant, directory, svnant

I want to checkout project, get the revision number, build jar with that number in menifest, on the server with a web interface. There are some other minor steps in the whole process, but that's the main goal. everything in the build script is working fine locally, but I always get stuck when it is done on the server. when I try to use svnant  task on the project I checked out, it's telling me the parent dir is not a working copy, so I tried  a copy first, then  the whole project again into that  copy, it's still telling me that the parent dir (the first  edition) is not a working copy.

what sould I do?

p.s. I have tried all possible combination of , , , . none of them worked. can anyone else get the  in svnant work? I always get error as following:

java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.tigris.subversion.svnant.commands.WcVersion.getWorkingCopySumary(Unknown Source)
        at org.tigris.subversion.svnant.commands.WcVersion.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.tigris.subversion.svnant.commands.SvnCommand.executeCommand(Unknown Source)
        at org.tigris.subversion.svnant.SvnTask.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
..........

can anyone help with either question?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, check that you have the same version of SVN installed on server and on client (svn --version).

Also, I would like to recall you that svnant is binding to SVN 1.5 and if on server side you have 1.6 version, you can get similar behavior.

**How to resolve the issue**: switch your script from javahl to svnkit. I.e. add svnkit jars to your classpath and add to all svnant related commands appropriate hint:

```
javahl="false" svnkit="true"
```